# Selenium/Watir can't detect Chromedriver, even though it's in my path (Windows 7)

Tags: selenium, watir, selenium-chromedriver

I know there's another question similar to this, but the link provided by the answerer is out of date (and when I dig into the current Watir documentation I only find info on Windows 8.1; I am on Windows 7, and the step that doc suggests for resolving this is not helping me per below)

I am attempting to execute a test using Watir/minitest (along the lines of rake ci:setup:minitest test TEST=test/full_path/happypath_test.rb), and it chokes on the following:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError: Unable to find the chromedriver exec
utable. Please download the server from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.c
om/index.html and place it somewhere on your PATH. More info at http://code.goog
le.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver.
```

The Watir documentation and error message both point to the PATH. However, I have just downloaded the latest version of Chromedriver (2.12, it appears) and plonked the exe in a folder that I have confirmed is in my PATH (specifically c:/Ruby193/bin - yes I know I'm on an old Ruby version; alas not something I can update for this project)

I know Chromedriver is present because I can run it from irb:

```
require 'watir-webdriver
```

followed by

```
b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
```

This launches a chrome window just fine. But when I actually try to execute a test it gives the "can't find chromedriver" error.

I've run bundle install to try and be sure I'm on the right versions of things and don't know what else to do. Any help, please?

Answer (score 0):

### Specify the `driver_path` directly to Selenium.

Simply call this before launching your new browser window:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Service.driver_path = "/absolute/path/to/chromedriver"
```

This also has the benefit of not requiring you to muck up your `PATH` and you can checkthis into your repo (of course, make the path dynamic to your project root directory, etc.).

Answer (score -1):

I found real nice posts [here](https://pushprajsingh05.wordpress.com/2014/12/23/how-to-run-watir-tests-on-different-browsers/) and [here](https://pushprajsingh05.wordpress.com/2015/01/02/how-to-place-the-browser-binary-in-watir-project-default-location/). You can configure in super easy steps.

I have tried and tested working superb.

From post 1:
Change from `firefox` to chrome (wherever you have instantiated the browser ), so that it will become:
`@browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome`

Now if you are on Windows, copy paste the downloaded binary file in `C:/Windows` directory`

Second post tells about how to change the default path `c:\windows` to your project's custom path. Its interesting and helpful. Take a look for sure.